# What to use - While vs Cursor to improve performance of procedure in sybase

Tags: t-sql, sybase

I am trying to improve the performance of stored procedure which is currently taking more than 5 hours..
I have done below things to improve performance of this procedure-
-- i have created indexes for each table.
--Instead of count(*), i am using count(1).

But i am just wondering what to use in place of while loop, if possible, Can i use cursor? will there be any impact because i have read cursors do take a lot of time in processing..

Summary of procedure:
- Calculating row count of a table.
- for every row count selecting paramters.
- These parameters are being used by another procedure for the execution.

```
     DECLARE @lnTotalCount INT


   SELECT @lnTotalCount = COUNT(*) FROM 
      firstTable chksts


  SELECT @lnRecordCount = 1, @lnRowsProcessed =0
  WHILE @lnRecordCount <= @lnTotalCount
        BEGIN

        --  SET ROWCOUNT 1

          SELECT  @lcCKPY_REF_ID  = ckck.CKPY_REF_ID,
            @lnCKCK_SEQ_NO        = ckck.CKCK_SEQ_NO,
            @lcPYPY_ID            = ckck.PYPY_ID,
            @lnCKCK_CK_NO         = ckck.CKCK_CK_NO,
            @ldtCKCK_CASHED_DT    = ckck.CKCK_CASHED_DT,
            @ldtCKCK_PRINTED_DT   = ckck.CKCK_PRINTED_DT,
            @ldtCKCK_REISS_DT     = ckck.CKCK_REISS_DT,
            @lcCKCK_TYPE          = ckck.CKCK_TYPE,
            @lcCKCK_PAYEE_NAME    = ckck.CKCK_PAYEE_NAME,
            @lcCKCK_CURR_STS      = LTRIM(RTRIM(chksts.[TRANSACTION])),
            @lnCKST_SEQ_NO        = ckck.CKST_SEQ_NO,
            @lcCKCK_REISS_USUS_ID = ckck.CKCK_REISS_USUS_ID,
            @lnCKCK_LOCK_TOKEN    = ckck.CKCK_LOCK_TOKEN,
            @ldtATXR_SOURCE_ID    = ckck.ATXR_SOURCE_ID,
            @lnBPID_CK_NO         = chksts.SERIAL_NUMBER

          FROM
             firstTable chksts,
             secondTable ckck,
             thirdTable bpid

          WHERE ckck.CKPY_REF_ID   = bpid.CKPY_REF_ID
            AND bpid.BPID_CK_NO    = chksts.SERIAL_NUMBER
            AND ckck.CKCK_SEQ_NO   = bpid.CKCK_SEQ_NO
            AND ckck.CKCK_CURR_STS IN ('03','X3') 
            AND chksts.ID = @lnRecordCount
 IF(@@ROWCOUNT<>0) /* 1.5 If-Else condition*/
      BEGIN  
      EXEC @lnRetCd = ABProcedure
                  NULL,
                  NULL,
                  @lcCKPY_REF_ID,
                  @lnCKCK_SEQ_NO,
                  @lcPYPY_ID,
                  @lnCKCK_CK_NO,
                  @ldtCKCK_CASHED_DT,
                  @ldtCKCK_PRINTED_DT,
                  @ldtCKCK_REISS_DT,
                  @lcCKCK_TYPE,
                  @lcCKCK_PAYEE_NAME,
                  @lcCKCK_CURR_STS,
                  @lnCKST_SEQ_NO,
                  @lcCKCK_REISS_USUS_ID,
                  @lnCKCK_LOCK_TOKEN,
                  @ldtATXR_SOURCE_ID

           SELECT @lnRowsProcessed = @lnRowsProcessed + @@ROWCOUNT
      SELECT @lnRecordCount = @lnRecordCount + 1
```

Comment: When cursors are "too slow" it is because they execute one row at a time.  Sometimes row by row is for the best.  You're already doing that.  Without knowing what ABProcedure does, it's impossible to tell what you can do to, or even whether you should, refactor into a set-based logic.

Comment: the problem is that i can't change anything in ABProcedure, secondTable and ThirdTable. The only table i can touch is the firstTable and i have already created index for that.